# Low Poly to High Poly, Quad Based Meshes

Tags: modifiers, workflow

I'm pretty new to Blender, so I apologize for any obvious questions. My usual workflow when building simple structural, non-organic assets is..

1. Build a quad based low poly version
2. Duplicate, sub-divide, add control loops for high poly version
3. Optimize low poly version into triangles (feels like removing the support structure from under a new house right after you build it) for game export.

The problem with this workflow is when you have to go back and make changes to the structure - Have to convert low poly triangles back into quads, or remove all of the control loops from the high poly.

I've tried keeping a copy of the quad based low poly, but having 3 meshes to update adds even more work. Typically the updates are so simple that it is easier to update all 3 meshes than to recreate the optimized low poly again. Especially when the optimized version becomes radically different, due to an excessive number of removed edges.

I was wondering if anyone has found a better workflow that generates less work. One idea I've considered is using a modifier to optimize the low poly instead of doing it manually, which would make it non-destructive, but that is giving up a lot of control, and I'm not sure how good the optimization modifiers are at this. I've also thought about finding some type of add-on modifier that allows stacking control loops through its modifier to make them non-destructive.

Something that would really help would be a mesh-edit modifier. Something that preserves a specific stage of mesh editing while stacking new edits on top.

Anyway, I'm looking for better methods or a simpler workflow. I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure why you duplicate the model and subdivide it? and why you have to make changes to all three models?  I've never seen a work flow like that, what is the purpose of doing it?

Comment: The subdivided duplicate is for baking normals and other information from a high poly to the low poly. For low poly game props and such. The low poly version is used to export to the game engine. The high poly version is used primarily for baking textures for the low poly version, but could also be used to render images, videos, etc. You wouldn't normally have to make changes to them, but I find myself doing this more than I probably should. For example, if you find out your game characters have a sitting height higher than your bench prop's seat height.

Comment: I think it would be hard to have a mesh-edit modifier. I have seen similar things in maya and houdini but they usually fail to do the right thing with the source mesh changes. I think that you do now, even if you need to redo some parts, are the best way. You could maybe add a triangulate modifier on top and only split triangles when you feel that you need control.

Comment: Do you typically use the decimate modifier to optimize redundant edges? I usually have a difficult time finding the perfect ratio factor. One that leaves all shape defining edges, but removes everything else. It would be great to have a modifier that did this by default, or through some type of checkbox. Also, you are correct about the edit poly modifier not working well when you change underlying geometry in most apps. I didn't really think about that until you mentioned it, though. Not much better than having a copy around.

Comment: @Robert, You could, instead of duplicating your low poly model, just add a multiresolution modifier to your low poly model.  you can click the subdivide button to add resolution to the modiifer.  this is indestructable, because at any time you can delete the modifier and everything will return to normal.  also, the multiresolution modifier saves every change you make for every level of detail.  However, this method only really works when you are using sculpting to add the detail, but I think it's a good method.  You can bake the detail to textures for video games, so this could be useful.